# How to deal with trait types?

Tags: rust, traits

I come from JVM world and I'm struggling with dealing with the traits. My goal is to provide an interface (that what it would be called in Java) that would represent the time provider, so I could use 'real' implementation in production environment and 'fake' in the tests, so I could stub the time.

In Java I'd have

```java
interface Clock {
    Instant now();
}

class UtcClock implements Clock {
    Instant now() {
         return Instant.now();
    }
}
```

and then I could use `Clock` type as any other type.

In Rust I have

```rust
pub trait Clock {
    fn now(&self) -> DateTime<Utc>;
}

pub struct UtcClock;

impl Clock for UtcClock {
    fn now(&self) -> DateTime<Utc> {
        return Utc::now();
    }
}
```

However to be able to use dynamic type `Clock` in Rust and to move it between threads I have to used boxed type e.g. `Arc<dyn Clock + Send + Sync>` which wouldn't be required if I'd use concrete type `UtcClock`.
Is provided solution of using traits idiomatic in Rust? Or there are other techniques to decouple the 'interface' and the implementation?
If it is OK then is there any way to make it look better than `Arc<dyn Clock + Send + Sync>`?

Comment: *I have to used boxed type* — The Java version is also boxed (almost everything in Java is boxed). You also don't _have_ to use the boxed trait object in many cases as generics suffice. *move it between threads* — nothing in Java prevents you from sending data across threads that isn't thread safe, so it's not a 1-to-1 comparison.

Comment: Can't you require that all implementations of `Clock` are also `Send` and `Sync` with `pub trait Clock: Send + Sync`?

Comment: You could also define `pub Clock: Send + Sync + Clone` and move clones into each thread instead of wrapping it in an `Arc`.

Comment: Might be worth revisiting Chapter 17 from the book, i.e. [using trait objects](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html). The question is also 
a bit vague without showing how the construct will be used. It is one concern to have constraints on a type in order to share is safely across threads, but another one to make it more idiomatic. Type aliases exist, but you might not need trait objects or shared values in the first place.

Comment: @Jmb With that approach it doesn't _have_ to be `Sync`, only `Send`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use a trait object (i.e. a `dyn Clock` of some kind), you may also be able to use regular generics:

```rust
fn use_clock<T: Clock>(clock: T) {
  let time = clock.now();
  // ...
}
```

Though I imagine you'll have a struct containing various "services" and having lots of generics everywhere might get slightly messy.

As for trait objects, if you just want to "not have to think about it" and get Java-like behaviour, an `Arc<dyn Clock>` will largely do what you want, other than thread-safety related traits. To resolve those issues, you can write `Arc<dyn Clock + Send + Sync + 'static>`, but I prefer to make these supertraits:

```rust
trait Clock: Send + Sync + 'static /* + whatever other traits you want */ {
  // ...
}
```

Note, this syntax **doesn't do inheritance** like the equivalent would in Java. Instead it imposes the restriction that: **types which implement `Clock` must also implement `Send`, etc**. Especially when working with unit structs (which are `Send + Sync + 'static` implicitly), moving the constraints to the trait definition can help cut down on boilerplate.

There's also type aliases, which essentially allow you to change the "spelling" of a type:

```rust
type ArcClock = Arc<dyn Clock + Send + Sync + 'static>;
```

and then you can use `ArcClock` like a regular type. Note, to the compiler, `ArcClock` is literally the same thing as `Arc<dyn Clock + ...>`.

As an aside, trait objects are often looked down upon in Rust for "bad performance". While it is true that calling a method on a trait object is generally harder to optimize than a regular monomorphized generic and requires an extra pointer indirection, this overhead is likely fairly small unless you're calling the method in a tight loop.

For example, in the case of a web server that stores the time a user was created, the overhead of the trait object will be negligible. FWIW, all java method calls behave in this way, so at worst you'll get Java-tier performance.

Comment: FWIW, in terms of Java-tier performance, wouldn't that only be true for Java implementations without JIT optimization? I wonder if there are any LLVM or native code JIT optimizers... There is compiler speculative in-lining and processor branch prediction though.

Comment: TBH I'm not an expert on JVM performance details, I used the term "Java-tier" because the performance is likely to be comparable. FWIW, LLVM can replace trait objects with regular static dispatch as an optimization in some cases. I'm not sure if Hotspot can do similar, but if so, I'm going to hazard a guess that the set of cases where this applies is broadly similar between Rust and Java. Anyways, for something like a system clock call, the difference is likely to be negligible anyways

Answer (score 2):

`Arc<dyn Clock + Send + Sync>` seems likely to be best, unless you're able to use `&dyn Clock + Send + Sync`. You can then use an alias type to make it look better, e.g. `type DynClock = Arc<dyn Clock + Send + Sync>;`. See [the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#creating-type-synonyms-with-type-aliases) and [the reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/type-aliases.html).